# Modify timing of a camera tracking

Tags: animation, tracking

Let's say I have some movie footage (250 frames, say), do motion tracking, and solve for camera. Now I want to play  through the tracking and associated background footage at a different pace. For example, I might first run through the footage and tracking normally, frames 1 to 250; then rest at frame 250 for 10 frames; then go backwards from frame 250 to 150; then jump cut to frame 50; then go forward from 50 to 100 in slo-mo. Note that for the 3D-objects I want to embed, normal timing applies (i.e., as if there were a normal animation with total duration of 250+10+100+2*50=460 frames). However, the *camera position* and the *background image from the movie* should be kept in sync, e.g., at animation frame 300, according to the above pattern, the camera should be at the tracking position of frame 210 and the background image should accordingly be frame 210 of the original footage (as should be expected for the final result).

How can I achieve this, preferably by defining and editing the time mapping (animation frame -> tracking frame) in a single place?

(This might *almost* be achievable by first editing the footage accordingly and tracking over the the full length - but I suppose that would not be as reliable and in particular give problems with jump cuts, not to mention that changes in the timing require a complete redo)

Comment: You can bake the camera motion to keyframes.

Comment: @Leander But will that sync the footage timing? And that won't do such time remapping by itself, would it? But perhaps I'm just blindly looking at the whole thing from the wrong angle ..